# HTML/CSS - Right and left align on the same line?

Tags: html, css

First off, I know there are ways to make it so that text can be on the same line.  But I am not sure how to extend on this.  This is what I have so far:

[image: Should be all the way across]

How would I be able to make it so it goes all the way across without using tables?

This is the HTML portion:

```
<p style="float: left;" class="details"><a href="#Top">To Top</a></p>
<p style="float: right" class="details">Latest Version:  0.3.6.17 | Downloads: 12 | <a href="#">Download</a></p>
```

This is the CSS portion:

```
.details {
padding: 7px 15px;
margin: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
background: #111111;    
}
```

I would really hate to have to resort to tables for this.  Is there an easier way.  Thank you anyone who can help me.

Comment: What should go all the way across?  It seems as though 'To Top' and the other details section are already on the same "line" that spans the width of the page.  Aside from your margin / padding of the elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This diverges a bit from what you started with, but has been how I've done this in the past:

CSS:

```
.details {
  clear: both;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  margin: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
  background: #111111;
  text-align: right;
}

.toplink {
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="details">
  <span class="toplink">To Top</span>
  Latest Version:  0.3.6.17 | Downloads: 12 | Download
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  That works perfectly!  And I'm sorry for not stating it from the beginning.  I'm about to fall asleep any minute and I just wanted to get this done and over with haha.  Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline;` to your `.details` class and make sure the containing div is a block element and its background is set to gray.

Sinan.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
#right {
    float: right;
}

.details {
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 0;
}
</style>

<p class="details"><a href="#Top">To Top</a></p>
<p id="right" class="details">Latest Version:  0.3.6.17 | Downloads: 12 | <a href="#">Download</a></p>
```

The tricky part is that you have to zero out the top and bottom margins for both AND the line-height. If you do this, then floating right on the bottom element lines up.