# How to align left and right align multiple lines in HTML?

Tags: html, css, alignment

How do i left and right align text on multiple lines, e.g.:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Tums                                 29 │
│ Oxydativedecarboxilization          ATP │
│ appdata      C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

e.g.:

> [image]

**Note**: A single-line variant of this question has been asked before

Here's a sample of some attempts i've found on SO and elsewhere, and the situations where left+right align was tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Home Page</TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        .left {
            float: left;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
        }
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV>
        <P><SPAN class='left'>Tums</SPAN><SPAN class='right'>29</SPAN>
        <P><SPAN class='left'>Oxydativedecarboxilization</SPAN><SPAN class='right'>42</SPAN>
        <P><SPAN class='left'>appdata</SPAN><SPAN class='right'>C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local</SPAN>
    </DIV>

    <UL>
        <LI class='line1'><P class='left'>Tums<P class='right'>29
        <LI class='line2'><P class='left'>Oxydativedecarboxilization<P class='right'>42
        <LI class='line3'><P class='left'>appdata<P class='right'>C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local
    </UL>

    <DIV>
        <P class='left'>Tums<P class='right'>29
        <P class='left'>Oxydativedecarboxilization<P class='right'>42
        <P class='left'>appdata<P class='right'>C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Which renders incorrectly as:

> [image]

Desired rendering:

> [image]

**Bonus reading**

- [HTML/CSS - Right and left align on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639705/html-css-right-and-left-align-on-the-same-line)
- [Cross-browser CSS for left align and right align on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324694/cross-browser-css-for-left-align-and-right-align-on-the-same-line)

Comment: A lot of people seem to be suggesting "Just clear your floats". Since i don't know what that means, and modifying `P` to `overflow:hidden` breaks the site, i'll wait for some upvotes to hint which answers are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to clear your floats. http://jsfiddle.net/P7KuB/2/

```
<div>
<p><span class='left'>Tums</span><span class='right'>29</span></p>
<p><span class='left'>Oxydativedecarboxilization</span><span class='right'>42</span></p>
<p><span class='left'>appdata</span><span class='right'>C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local</span></p>
```

```
.left { float: left; }
.right { float: right; }
p { overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

.wrap { clear:both; }

```
<DIV>
    <P class="wrap"><SPAN class='left'>Tums</SPAN><SPAN class='right'>29</SPAN>
    <P class="wrap"><SPAN class='left'>Oxydativedecarboxilization</SPAN><SPAN class='right'>42</SPAN>
    <P class="wrap"><SPAN class='left'>appdata</SPAN><SPAN class='right'>C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local</SPAN>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HkybR/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="info">
    <div>
        <span class="left">Tums</span><span class="right">29</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="left">Oxydativedecarboxilization</span><span class="right">ATP</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="left">appdata</span><span class="right">C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local</span>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Could probably be more semantic.

**CSS:**

```css
.info {
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    font-size: 21px;
    clear: both;
}
.info > div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
}
.info .left {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<UL style="list-style-type: none;">
    <LI class='line1'>Tums<div class='right'>29</div></LI>
    <LI class='line2'>Oxydativedecarboxilization<div class='right'>42</div></LI>
    <LI class='line3'>appdata<div class='right'>C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local</div></LI>
</UL>
```

Renders as...
[image: Output of the above]

You may also need to change the margins of the UL element.

EDIT: I guess the clear method is a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your test case was way too complicated. Here is a working multi-line version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Home Page</TITLE>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
        .left {
            float: left;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
        }
        .clear {
            clear:both;
        }            
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV>
        <P class="left clear">Left</P>
        <P class="right">Right</P>
        <P class="left clear">Left</P>
        <P class="right">Right</P>
        <P class="left clear">Left</P>
        <P class="right">RightRightRightRightRightRight RightRight RightRight RightRight</P>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>​
```

Comment: i won't always be using `div-p-p-p`, sometimes it really will be `ul-li-li-li`

Comment: It doesn't matter. As long as they're block-level elements, you'll be golden. Note: when using lists, you'll have to remove the list styles. See list-style-type, margin, and padding in the CSS docs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Block_elements

Comment: Well, i'd still want the bullet marker to appear, just the stuff on the right aligned on the right.

Comment: OK, then don't touch `list-style-type`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS add

```
p, li { overflow:hidden; }
```

Example : http://jsbin.com/asulih/